# Error While running migrate command in Django with Postgresql database

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm working on a django project with **Django 2.2** and **Postgresql 10.11** as database with latest version of **psycopg2**. 
But when I run migrate command, below error happen for specific migration.

```py
Running migrations:
  Applying panelprofile.0003_auto_20191007_1700...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 535, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema.py", line 122, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 648, in _alter_field
    old_default = self.effective_default(old_field)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 233, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 212, in _effective_default
    default = field.get_default()
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\programs\python\marketpine-backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 797, in get_default
    return self._get_default()
TypeError: SET_NULL() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'collector', 'field', 'sub_objs', and 'using'
```

Here is the migration file that this error happened on:

```py
# Generated by Django 2.2 on 2019-10-07 13:30

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('panelprofile', '0002_auto_20191007_1655'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='smspanelinfo',
            name='api_key',
            field=models.TextField(),
        ),
    ]
```

And this is the model that migration belongs to:

```py
class SMSPanelInfo(models.Model):

    businessman = models.OneToOneField(Businessman, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    api_key = models.TextField()
    STATUS_CHOICES = [('1', 'ACTIVE_LOGIN'), ('0', 'INACTIVE'), ('2', 'ACTIVE')]
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='0')
    minimum_allowed_credit = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10000)
    credit = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1000)
    sms_farsi_cost = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    sms_english_cost = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def deactivate(self):

        """
        deactivates sms panel of the user in kavenegar
        :return:
        """

        ClientManagement().deactivate_sms_panel(self.api_key)
        self.status = SMSPanelStatus.INACTIVE
        self.save()

    def activate(self):

        """
        activates sms panel on kavenegar
        :return:
        """
        ClientManagement().activate_sms_panel(self.api_key)
        self.status = SMSPanelStatus.ACTIVE_LOGIN
        self.save()

    def create_sms_panel(self, user: Businessman, password: str):
        client = ClientManagement()
        info = client.add_user(user, password)
        info.businessman = user
        info.save()
        return info

    def update_panel_info(self):
        client = ClientManagement()
        client.fetch_user(self.businessman)

        self.api_key = info.api_key

        self.credit = info.credit
        self.sms_farsi_cost = info.sms_farsi_cost
        self.sms_english_cost = info.sms_english_cost

        self.save()

    def reduce_credit(self, amount: int):
        self.credit -= amount
        self.save()
```

**Update**

This the last migration that includes `api_key`

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='SMSPanelInfo',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('username', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
                ('api_key', models.TextField(default=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL)),
                ('status', models.CharField(choices=[('1', 'ACTIVE_LOGIN'), ('0', 'INACTIVE'), ('2', 'ACTIVE')], default='0', max_length=1)),
                ('minimum_allowed_credit', models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10000)),
                ('credit', models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1000)),
                ('sms_farsi_cost', models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()),
                ('sms_english_cost', models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()),
                ('businessman', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Anyone knows where is the problem?

Comment: Show the last migration that included api_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up the `on_delete` parameter for foreign keys with the `default` value for other fields.

If you want to add a default value *null* to the field `api_key`, alter them both in models and your previous migration file:

```
# in models.py
api_key = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)

# in 0002_auto_20191007_1655
('api_key', models.TextField(default=None, null=True)),
```

Or, if you have not yet migrated your files, delete both `0002_auto_20191007_1655` and `0003_auto_20191007_1700` and run makemigrate/migrate again.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Boris. Your solution fixed the problem.